# Send data to PHP Class and post in in SQL database

Tags: javascript, php, oop

I am quite new in PHP and all web development. I am wondering if someone could help me with data flow. I am trying to send form data to a PHP file and then call the function from the class to send data to the sql database. Right now, I don't have any PHP extensions in VS Code so I could debug it and see what is not working. And ofcourse in DOM there is only JS file and PHP which holds HTML code.
This is my code in JavaScript where it takes all user given data and sends it to php. But in form it consists of three static inputs, and then there is a switcher, which displays a user defined view.
`

```
    //Function check for correct input with .value() call
    //If it returns 'true' it proceedss with further validation of additional fields that change dynamically.
    //When all fields have passed validation function begins to POST FormData to PHP file for backend work.
    if(validate.test(sku) && validate.test(name) && validatePrice.test(price)){
        if(validateAdditional(this.switcher)){
            let xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xml.open("POST", "./backend/product.php", true);
            xml.onload = () => {
                if(xml.readyState == 4 && xml.status == 200){
                    let response = xml.response;
                    alert(response);
                    form.reset()
                    history.back();
                }
            };
            let formData = new FormData(form);
            xml.send(formData);
        }
    }else{
        alert("Please check if there is not any spaces or special characters added");
    }
}
```

Then I created a class that will hold all of the network calls to post/read/edit/delete data from the sql database.

```
class DatabaseCalls{
    private $servername = "localhost";
    private $username = "root";
    private $password = "";
    private $dbname = "scandiweb";

    public function insertData($dataQuery){
        $connection = new mysqli($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, $this->dbname);

        if(!$connection){
            return die("Connection failed" . $connection->connect_error);
        }

        if($connection->query($dataQuery)){
            return "Done";
        }else{
            echo "Error: " . $dataQuery . "<br>" . $connection->connect_error;
        }
        $connection->close();
    }
}
```

And then where there are model call network functions to send it to sql. JS file post data to models file. And then procedurally create the Product object and call the first function where I populate the input data.

```
<?php
include("netowking.php");

$sku = $_POST['sku'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$memory = $_POST['dvd-memory'];

$dvdProduct = new Product($sku, $name, $price, $memory);
echo $dvdProduct->insertQuery();



class Product extends DatabaseCalls{
    private $sku;
    private $name;
    private $price;
    private $memory;

    public function __construct($sku, $name, $price, $memory){
        $this->sku = $sku;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->price = $price;
        $this->memory = $memory;
    }

    public function insertQuery(){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO dvd (SKU, Name, Price, Memory)
        VALUES ('$sku', '$name', '$price', '$memory')";

        $response = $this->insertData($sql);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

And for context I will all also HTML code.

```
    <form class="input" name="input">
        <div>
        <label for="sku">SKU:</label>
        <input id="sku" type="text" name="sku" placeholder="#SKU">
        </div>

        <div>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="#name">
        </div>

        <div>
        <label for="price">Price ($):</label>
        <input id="price" type="text" name="price" placeholder="#price">
        </div>

        <div class="switcher">
            <h3>Type Switcher</h3>

            <select name="select" id="select">
                <option selected disabled>Choose a type</option>
                <option value="dvd">DVD</option>
                <option value="furniture">Furniture</option>
                <option value="book">Book</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="switchContent">

            <div class="dvd-mem", id="dvd">
                <p>DVD-disc</p>
                <label for="dvd-memory">Size(MB):</label>
                <input id="dvd-memory" type="text" name="dvd-memory" placeholder="Please enter MB amount here">
                <p>Please enter amount of disc memory in MB.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="furniture" id="furniture">
                <p>Furniture</p>

                <div>
                <label for="height">Height(CM):</label>
                <input id="height" type="text" name="height" placeholder="Enter height in here">
                </div>

                <div>
                <label for="width">Width(CM):</label>
                <input id="width" type="text" name="width" placeholder="Enter width in here">
                </div>

                <div>
                <label for="lenght">Height(CM):</label>
                <input id="lenght" type="text" name="lenght" placeholder="Enter lenght in here">
                </div>

                <p>Please enter all dimensions of furniture</p>
            </div>

            <div class="book" id="book">
                <p>Book</p>
                <label for="weight">Weight(KG):</label>
                <input id="weight" type="text" name="weight" placeholder="Please enter weight in KG">
                <p>Please enter weight of book</p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: I see three immediate problems. First: `$connection->connect_error` specifically returns errors involving the connection. If the connection is good but your query fails in the `insertData` method, you'll want `$connection->error` instead. Second: in your `Product` class's `insertQuery` method, those variables don't exist. You need to access the class properties via `$this->sku`, `$this->name`, etc. instead. And third: look into prepared statements. The way you're building the query right now is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks and it will fail on any value containing a `'` character.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out these three problems. I fixed them, but still I dont have any result. First thing is that the data is not added to sql database and the second thing is that no response comes back to JS file not even an error thats why my head is exploding :D

Comment: Can it be because all form input fields ar not filled out and in creating FormObject in JS file XML request does not send because of that?